# Vim: Select rectangular block past end of line

Tags: vim

How do I select a rectangular block of text which extends beyond the end of the line in Vim?

Suppose that I have

```
aa
bbb
cc
dddd
ee
```

I would like to select a rectangular block that extends four characters on all lines. If `_` is considered white-space, then I want:

```
aa__
bbb_
cc__
dddd
ee__
```

The rectangular visual block, `C-v`, only extends as far as the end of the last line selected:

[image: rectangular select which extends beyond the end of the line]

In Emacs, I can do what I want using `C-x <SPC>` (`rectangle-mark-mode`). ;)

Comment: You can press `$` after selecting your block to extend the selection to the end of all the lines. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim: how to enter insert-anywhere/canvas mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623366/vim-how-to-enter-insert-anywhere-canvas-mode)

Comment: @phd while the answer of that question is a valid answer to this question too, I would still not vote for a duplicate, since the question has a different usecase and also at least one valid solution (see the comment of Matthew) which would not be a valid answer for the other question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### blockwise visual mode with ragged border

To extend the blockwise visual selection to the end of all covered lines, you can press `$` to switch Vim into a "ragged border" selection mode. This "trick" is mentioned at [`:help v_b_A`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#v_b_A):

> With a blockwise selection, A{string} will append {string} to the end of
>   block on every line of the block.  There is some differing behavior where the
>   block RHS is not straight, due to different line lengths:
>
> 1. Block was created with $
>      In this case the string is appended to the end of each line.
> 2. Block was created with {move-around}
>      In this case the string is appended to the end of the block on each line, and whitespace is inserted to pad to the end-of-block column.

#### virtual edit

Another way to solve this is via the [`'virtualedit'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27virtualedit%27) option:

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

This makes the space following the end of the line accessible to cursor movements, so you can extend the selection as much as you need. Yanking that text will have whitespace padding inserted to make a rectangular block, so the behavior is different to the above alternative.

Comment: Virtual edit is definitely what I'm looking for!  I'm not clear how the blockwise visual mode with ragged border accomplishes the same thing, though.  That seems to append text at the end of ragged lines rather than making a rectangular selection padded with spaces. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LoremIpsum That's why Ingo states correctly that the behavior is different. Without `virtualedit=all` you will not receive a rectangle. But for coding cases, you usually don't want to insert useless whitespaces. And if you want to align code there are better ways ([vim-easy-algin](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) for example)

Answer (score -1):

Using substitution

```
:%s,^..$,&__,g | %s,^...$,&_,g

: ............ command
% ............ whole file
^ ............ begining of line
.. ........... two characters
$ ............ end of line
& ............ the whole search pattern
__ ........... (plus) the chars we want
g ............ globally
| ............ another command (this time for 3 chars)
```